# Negative Binomial Mixture in PyMC

Tags: python, statistics, modeling, pymc, markov-chains

I am trying to fit a Negative binomial mixture with PyMC.
It seems I do something wrong, because the predictive doesn't look at all similar to the input data.
The problem is probably in the prior of the Negative binomial parameters.
Any suggestions?

```
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    import pymc as mc
    n = 3 #Number of components of the mixture
    ndata = len(data)

    dd = mc.Dirichlet('dd', theta=(1,)*n)
    category = mc.Categorical('category', p=dd, size=ndata)

    kme = KMeans(n) # This is not needed but it is to help convergence
    kme.fit(data[:,newaxis])
    alphas = mc.TruncatedNormal('alphas', kme.cluster_centers_[:,0], 0.1, a=0. ,b=100000 ,size=n)
    means = mc.TruncatedNormal('means', kme.cluster_centers_[:,0],0.1,a=0.0 ,b=100000, size=n)

    @mc.deterministic
    def mean(category=category, means=means):
        return means[category]

    @mc.deterministic
    def alpha(category=category, alphas=alphas):
        return alphas[category]

    obs = mc.NegativeBinomial('obs', mean, alpha, value=data, observed = True)

    predictive = mc.NegativeBinomial('predictive', mean, alpha)

    model = mc.Model({'dd': dd,
                  'category': category,
                  'alphas': alphas,
                  'means': means,
                  'predictive':predictive,
                  'obs': obs})

    mcmc = mc.MCMC( model )
    mcmc.sample( iter=n_samples, burn=int(n_samples*0.7))
```

Comment: I simulated some data with `data = list(mc.rnegative_binomial(100., 1000., size=10)) + list(mc.rnegative_binomial(200., 1000., size=10)) + list(mc.rnegative_binomial(300., 1000., size=10))`.  Does this match your intention with such a model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly implemented a Bayesian estimation of a mixture of three distributions, but the MCMC model gives wrong-looking values.

The problem is that `category` is not converging quickly enough, and the parameters in `means`, `alphas`, and `dd` run away from the good values before `category` decides which points belong to which distribution.

```
data = np.atleast_2d(list(mc.rnegative_binomial(100., 10., size=s)) +
    list(mc.rnegative_binomial(200., 1000., size=s)) +
    list(mc.rnegative_binomial(300., 1000., size=s))).T
nsamples = 10000
```

You can see that the posterior for `category` is wrong by visualizing it:

```
G = [data[np.nonzero(np.round(mcmc.trace("category")[:].mean(axis=0)) == i)]
    for i in range(0,3) ]
plt.hist(G, bins=30, stacked = True)
```

[image: category posteriors of the input data, no initialization]

Expectation-maximization is the classic approach to stabilize the latent variables, but you can also use the results of the quick-and-dirty k-means fit to provide initial values for the MCMC:

```
category = mc.Categorical('category', p=dd, size=ndata, value=kme.labels_)
```

Then the estimates converge to reasonable-looking values.

[image: category posteriors using kmeans to initialize]

For your prior on alpha, you can just use the same distribution for all of them:

```
alphas = mc.Gamma('alphas', alpha=1, beta=.0001 ,size=n)
```

This problem is not specific to the negative binomial distribution; Dirichlet-mixtures of normal distributions fail in the same way; it results from having a high-dimensional categorical distribution that MCMC is not efficient at optimizing.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This sounds worth trying! About EM dou you know of any good iplementation? I failed to inplement it: the difficoulties I foind is that NB is discrete and using responsibilities on each values I would get float and the fact that there is not closed form for the extimation of its parameters (I can use optimization to het a MLE but it makes everything less stable)