# first use of PyMc fails

Tags: pymc

I am new to PyMc and would like to know why this code doesn't work. I already spent hours on this but I miss something. Could anyone help me ?

question I want to address:

- I have a set of Npts measures that show 3 bumps, so I want to model this as the sum of 3 gaussians (assuming the measures are noisy and the gaussian approx is ok) ==> I want to estimate 8 parameters: the relative  weights of the bumps (i.e. 2 params), their 3 means and their 3 variances.
- I want this approach wide enough to be applicable on other sets that may not have the same bumps, so I take loose flat priors.

problem:
My code below gives me crappy estimations. what's wrong ? thx

```
"""
hypothesis: multimodal distrib sum of 3 gaussian distributions

model description:
* p1, p2, p3 are the probabilities for a point to belong to gaussian 1, 2 or 3
 ==> p1, p2, p3 are the relative weights of the 3 gaussians

* once a point is associated with a gaussian,
it is distributed normally according to the parameters mu_i, sigma_i of the gaussian
but instead of considering sigma, pymc prefers considering tau=1/sigma**2

* thus, PyMc must guess 8 parameters: p1, p2, mu1, mu2, mu3, tau1, tau2, tau3

* priors on p1, p2 are flat between 0.1 and 0.9 ==> 'pm.Uniform' variables
with the constraint p2<=1-p1. p3 is deterministic ==1-p1-p2

* the 'assignment' variable assigns each point to a gaussian, according to probabilities p1, p2, p3

* priors on mu1, mu2, mu3 are flat between 40 and 120 ==> 'pm.Uniform' variables

* priors on sigma1, sigma2, sigma3 are flat between 4 and 12 ==> 'pm.Uniform' variables
"""

    import numpy as np
    import pymc as pm

    data = np.loadtxt('distrib.txt')
    Npts = len(data)

    mumin = 40
    mumax = 120
    sigmamin=4
    sigmamax=12

    p1 = pm.Uniform("p1",0.1,0.9)
    p2 = pm.Uniform("p2",0.1,1-p1)
    p3 = 1-p1-p2
    assignment = pm.Categorical('assignment',[p1,p2,p3],size=Npts)
    mu = pm.Uniform('mu',[mumin,mumin,mumin],[mumax,mumax,mumax])
    sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma',[sigmamin,sigmamin,sigmamin],
                       [sigmamax,sigmamax,sigmamax])
    tau = 1/sigma**2

    @pm.deterministic
    def assign_mu(assi=assignment,mu=mu):
        return mu[assi]

    @pm.deterministic
    def assign_tau(assi=assignment,sig=tau):
        return sig[assi]

    hypothesis = pm.Normal("obs", assign_mu, assign_tau, value=data, observed=True)

    model = pm.Model([hypothesis, p1, p2, tau, mu])
    test = pm.MCMC(model)
    test.sample(50000,burn=20000) # conservative values, let's take a coffee... 

    print('\nguess\n* p1, p2 = ',
           np.mean(test.trace('p1')[:]),' ; ',
           np.mean(test.trace('p2')[:]),' ==> p3 = ',
           1-np.mean(test.trace('p1')[:])-np.mean(test.trace('p2')[:]),
           '\n* mu = ',
           np.mean(test.trace('mu')[:,0]),' ; ',
           np.mean(test.trace('mu')[:,1]),' ; ',
           np.mean(test.trace('mu')[:,2]))

    print('why does this guess suck ???!!!')
```

I can send the data file 'distrib.txt'. It is ~500 kb and data are plotted below. For instance last run gave me:

```
p1, p2 = 0.366913192214  ;  0.583816452532  ==> p3 = 0.04927035525400003
mu =  77.541619286  ;  75.3371615466  ;  77.2427165073
```

while there are obviously bumps around ~55, ~75 and ~90, with probabilities around ~0.2, ~0.5 and ~0.3

[image: histogram of the data (20k points == Npts)]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the problem described here: [Negative Binomial Mixture in PyMC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475293/negative-binomial-mixture-in-pymc)

The problem is the Categorical variable converges too slowly for the three component distributions to get even close.

First, we generate your test data:

```
data1 = np.random.normal(55,5,2000)
data2 = np.random.normal(75,5,5000)
data3 = np.random.normal(90,5,3000)
data=np.concatenate([data1, data2, data3])
np.savetxt("distrib.txt", data)
```

Then we plot the histogram, colored by the posterior group assignment:

```
tablebyassignment = [data[np.nonzero(np.round(test.trace("assignment")[:].mean(axis=0)) == i)] for i in range(0,3) ]
plt.hist(tablebyassingment, bins=30, stacked = True)
```

[image: Stacked histogram with poor discrimination between clusters]
This will eventually converge, but not quickly enough to be useful to you.

You can fix this problem by guessing the values of assignment before starting MCMC:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kme = KMeans(3)
kme.fit(np.atleast_2d(data).T)
assignment = pm.Categorical('assignment',[p1,p2,p3],size=Npts, value=kme.labels_)
```

Which gives you:
[image: Stacked histogram showing separation of three lumps]
Using k-means to initialize the categorical may not work all of the time, but it is better than not converging.